# Testing Django web app with Hudson and Selenium

Tags: django, hudson

This might be a newbie question for Hudson. I am trying to setup Selenium testing for my Django website in my Hudson CI server. The question is, the Hudson will use subversion to checkout my Django code into its own path, how do I "deploy" the code into the same server for testing? This is not a question about deploying django, but instead how to access the source file in hudson workspace. Most tutorials/blogs is about building and running tests, but I couldn't find useful information about how to setup the web application on the server to run the test against.

1) Should I write some shell script to copy the source files from the hudson workspace? Is there an environment variable to use to access the workspace? 
2) Is there a tutorial on how to grab web app files in hudson workspace and deploy them? I am sure this apply for other technologies like PHP as well.

Thanks!

Comment: In Hudson you can define multiple sources from where you can checkout and define where the working copy will be located inside the workspace of Hudson. So you can simply define a second area where to put Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, shell script is good.  There are plugins for other types of scripting, for example [Python](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Python+Plugin), if that's how you roll.

There is also the [Copy Artifact Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Copy+Artifact+Plugin), which you may find helpful.

Workspace is accessed via %WORKSPACE% or $WORKSPACE.